# Alternative of std::atomic<bool> before c++11 or same behavior

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, stl, atomic

What is the alternative of below mentioned statement in previous version of C++ ( before C++11)

OR

We can achieve the same behavior ?

file:- std::atomic sample{false};

Comment: The C++ memory model didn't have threads before C++11, so no, nothing in the standard

Answer (score 0):

@Mat is right that before C++11 there was not support for multi-threading - at least not with regards to the standard. However, if you find yourself in a situation where you have such an old compiler (for whatever reason) that you cannot use the C++11 memory model, I would suggest to give [boost::atomic](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/atomic.html) a try.